# Different decimal separator between ibatis and db

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, locale, ibatis

I have a web spring application that uses ibatis. This application can be installed in different servers and different DBs. The problem comes when I setup a server, for example, in English (DOT as decimal separator) and a DB in Italian (COMMA as decimal separator). Consequently the decimal separators are different. I have one transformation depending on the DB I'm using in each case, not a big deal in iBatis. Some examples of the where condition are (Other DBs are possible a part from those ones):

Oracle: `DECIMAL_COLUMN = TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(#STRING_VALUE#, '.', ','))`

SQLServer: `DECIMAL_COLUMN = REPLACE(#STRING_VALUE#, '.', ',')`

For that example I've got a "ORA-01722: invalid number". My question is: Is there any way to get the decimal separator for each type of DB in iBatis? So I can replace that to something like:

`DECIMAL_COLUMN = TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(#STRING_VALUE#, #SERVER_SIDE_DECIMAL_SEPARATOR#, #DATABASE_DECIMAL_SEPARATOR#))`

What ever other solution or work around is more than welcome.

Thanks

Comment: The decimal separator depends on your database configuration (e.g. NLS_* for oracle) do a replace is a bad pratice. You should keep your program settings complacent with your databases. Use the database functions to alter your session according its configuration (to set the proper number format). Search at google: database session parameters decimal separator (for oracle) and setting decimal separator for sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although didn't include his comment as a possible answer, I consider it a good possible solution. Here with a little bit of code

In Oracle case, altering the session to `,.` or `.,`:

`alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=',.';`

depending on the server's locale. Simply using DecimalFormatSymbols to get those values:

`String decimalSeparator = String.valueOf(new DecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator());`

`String groupingSeparator = String.valueOf(new DecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator());`

In SQL Server, setting up the session language to the same as the server side:

`SET LANGUAGE the_language;`

and getting the language using Locale:

`String language = Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage("en_US");`